# Open or closed Region in the plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

I am unsure whether the region
$$D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ (x , y) \in \mathbf {R}^2 :\;\; x^2 + y^2 \,\leq\, 1 - \frac {1}{n} \right\}$$ is closed or not.

When $n=1$ the region is defined by $ \left\{ (x , y) \in \mathbf {R}^2 :\;\; x^2 + y^2 \,\leq\, 0 \right\}$ is where I'm getting confused.

Can the region just be thought of as the area inside the unit circle and therefore closed?

Comment: $D=\{(x,y): x^{2}+y^{2} <1\}$. It is not closed.

Comment: Is the area inside the unit circle closed? How do you define “inside?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D$ is not closed set. It can be prooved by $D'\not\subseteq D$.

Let $p=(1,0)$. Then, for arbitary $\epsilon>0$, there exists natural number $n$ such that $n\epsilon>1$ because of the Archimedean property.

Then, $q=(\sqrt{1-\frac1n},0)\in B(p,\epsilon)$ and $q\in D$ because $\sqrt{1-\frac1n}^2+0^2\le1-\frac1{2n}$.

So, for arbitary $\epsilon>0, B(p,\epsilon)\cap D-{p}\neq\emptyset$.

So $p\in D'$, but $p\not\in D$.

The proof ends.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite unions of closed sets are not necessarily closed. In fact we can show that $D$ is the open ball of radius one around the origin:

The fact that $D \subseteq B_1(0)$ is trivial, as for all $n$, $$\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right\} \subseteq \left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1 \right\} = B_1(0).$$

The fact that $B_1(0) \subseteq D$ can be proved like so: Suppose $||x|| < 1$, then let $\varepsilon = 1 - ||x||^2$. By the Euclidean property, there exists $n$ such that $1/n < \varepsilon$, thus $x$ is in $$\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right\}.$$